# I want to select all Users which are not members of a Group with id=6

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship

My tables

1. users

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

2. group

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

3. group_users

| id | user_id | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 4 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 6 |

```
// All users which are members of group
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

```
// All groups user belong to
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
}
```

This is what I have tried to do. I think the problem is that I have to make the $users an array of ids that were fetched and I'm unable to do that. Please help

```
public function show(Group $group)
{
    //Fetching all members of the group
    $users = $group->users()->get()

    return Inertia::render('Clients/Show', [
            'users' => Group::whereNotIn('id', $users)->get()
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public function show(Group $group)
{
    //Fetching all members of the group
    $exceptId = $group->users()->pluck('users.id');

    return Inertia::render('Clients/Show', [
            //Here it will fetch all users except those with ids matching $exceptId array
            'users' => Group::whereNotIn('id', $exceptId)->get(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select users who don't have a relation, you can use [whereDoesntHave](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence):

```
$users = User
    ::whereDoesntHave('groups', fn($query) => $query->where('id', 1))
    ->get();
```

In this case I'm querying for all users who dont have a group with id 1 linked.

Comment: I actually want to query those who do not have relationship with group id=1

Comment: Allright, answer changed